# Retrofit call back time remain download file Android

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm implementing retrofit in my app. I use code below to getString and write to file from server.

```
Callback callback = new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse");
            File file = new File(fileDirectory);
            file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file,
                    XXX);
            try {
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(
                        new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
                osw.write(new String(response.body().string()));
                osw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i(TAG,"onFailure, getTermAndPoliciesDocument()");
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
    PortalService portalService = ServiceGeneratorDemo.createService(PortalService.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = portalService.getStringFromFile(AppSetting.Default.TERM_AND_POLICIES_DOC_NAME);
    call.enqueue(callback);
```

Now i want show information about download of that file. Like 1 - 100% to complete progress like below image. [image]. Anyone know how to callback time remain ?

Answer (score 3):

> Now i want show information about download of that file. Like 1 - 100% to complete progress

Your image shows time remaining, but once you know the percentage complete, you can calcuate the time yourself.  Here's how I found to get the percent progress update using Retrofit 2:

First, create a progress listener:

```
final ProgressResponseBody.ProgressListener progressListener = new ProgressResponseBody.ProgressListener() {
    @Override public void update(long bytesRead, long contentLength, boolean done) {
        int percent = (int)((100 * bytesRead) / contentLength);
        //Do something with the progress (I sent the event through EventBus)        
    }
};
```

Next, create a client as shown here, which will call the listener:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                    return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                            .body(new ProgressResponseBody(originalResponse.body(), progressListener))
                            .build();
                }
            })
            .build();
```

Finally, specify the client when building Reftrofit:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
  .client(client)
  .build()
```

It took me a while to get this figured out and I wish I could find the link that provided the final information, but this is the code I'm using.  (I thought it was on Future Studio but I don't see it.)